# Travel from the UK carrying cash

Tags: international-travel

I am traveling to asia and would like to take £6000 cash with me. What is the limit for one to travel out of the UK with cash?

Comment: Note that depending on where you're going in Asia, you may be required to declare that amount on arrival.  For example, Vietnam requires amounts greater than 5000 USD to be declared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any limit above which you are unable to take cash out of the UK, but if the total value of the currencies and negotiable instruments you hold is above €10,000 and you're leaving the EU, [you need to declare it](https://www.gov.uk/bringing-cash-into-uk). At the current exchange rates, €10,000 is depressing close to £10,000 (roughly £9,100 on the 10th January 2019).

Comment: Note that whatever the amount you may need to justify its origin or it could be seized on the spot.

Comment: How could it be seized, i have valid bank statements to show the money trace?

Comment: @Haris If you can prove it's yours, then that's fine. But you should expect to be delayed at departure as soon as the currency sniffing dog smells that money. Give yourself a few extra minutes.

Comment: @jcaron, not quite. There's a lower limit of 1000 GBP.